# @EnableAspectJAutoProxy does not work

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I am using Spring Boot, and I would like to use AspectJ with it.

The following works (of course):

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class RequestMappingAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    public void advice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, if `@Component` is removed and [`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableAspectJAutoProxy.html) is added, the following does not work.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

How to enable AspectJ auto proxy correctly?

Comment: With `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` you do not use AspectJ, but proxy-based Spring AOP. But probably that is what you want anyway.

Comment: Ofcourse it won't work... I you remove `@Component` no instance of the aspect will be created, hence no aspects available so nothing to use. You need both `@Component` and `@Aspect` to make it work (or define the aspect as a `@Bean` method). Either way an instance of the aspect has to be there to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wondering about the same thing, we ended up doing something similar to this:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
@Configuration("Main applicationContext")
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = {"com.where.ever"},
    excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(Aspect.class)})
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
    public SomeAspect someAspect() {
        return Aspects.aspectOf(SomeAspect.class);
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

This enabled us to just add the `@Aspect`-annotation on the aspects, which also wired them correctly. 
Might be that this was a pointless reply, however, it explains how we solved the issue - and not the actual solution to the problem. Let me know if you want this to be deleted.

Comment: There is nothing automatic about this... The aspect is created with an `@Bean` method so if you add a new aspect you need to add another method.

Comment: i don't understand why this is the accepted anwser. As M. Deinum says, spring aop  can only be applied to beans that are managed by a Spring container. 

  So its normal it not work if you remove @component from your aspect definition.

Answer (score 6):

You need both @EnableAspectJAutoProxy for the spring configuration and combination of @Aspect / @Component annotations

@EnableAspectJAutoProxy does the same thing as xml based <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>