# AspectJ @Before annotation issue

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm having some issues with AspectJ implementation!
I want to make a log method for methods with the @MyAnnotation annotation.

MyAnnotation.java :

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation{ }
```

MyAspect.java :

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyAspect.class.getName());

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.utils.aop.annotations.MyAnnotation)")
    public void logMyAspect() {
    }
    @Before("logMyAspect()")
    public void logMethod(JoinPoint jp) {
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();
        logger.info("Executing method: " + methodName);
    }
}
```

I'm using my @MyAnnotation before some of the service method of my project:

```
    @RolesAllowed({ "DEV", "GUI", "API" })
    @POST
    @Path("/getList")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    @MyAnnotation
    public Response getList(@Context final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,  
            FilterAndSortObject filterAndSortObject, 
            @QueryParam("offset") final int offset,
            @QueryParam("limit") final int limit)
    {
             ...
    }
```

I've also seen that I should use @EnableAspectJAutoProxy in my configuration class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class ServletContextClass implements ServletContextListener {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ServletContextClass.class);
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent sce) {
    ...
    }
...
}
```

However it doesn't seem to work. It doesn't log anything!
I used a breakpoint in the `logMethod(JoinPoint jp)` as well checking the result, without any success!

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802391/enableaspectjautoproxy-does-not-work

Comment: And please also make sure that the classes in which you are annotating methods are also Spring components. This is easily forgotten in Spring AOP. It would not be necessary in AspectJ, but Spring AOP only works for Spring-managed beans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to separate the pointcut and the handler method; in fact, I'm sure this is what causes your issue. The following aspect should work just fine:

```
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyAspect.class.getName());
    @Before("@annotation(com.utils.aop.annotations.MyAnnotation)")
    public void logMyAspect(JoinPoint jp) {
        String methodName = jp.getSignature().getName();
        logger.info("Executing method: " + methodName);
    }
}
```

You can also inspect your annotation values, in case it takes parameters:

```
@Before("@annotation(a)")
public void logMyAspect(JoinPoint jp, MyAnnotation a) {
    // conditional logging based on annotation contents
}
```

Comment: I've used separate pointcut and handler for this exact thing, that would not be the root cause of whatever issue he's having.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas This was literally the only difference between his aspect and the (working) one I've used in my project

Comment: That is not the problem.